# Get installed programs list both 32 and 64 bit programs

Tags: vb6, registry, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit

Below is my complete code which gets list of programs installed on a PC. But when the application is run in 64 bit pc the "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\" registry will automatically refer to "SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" due to registry redirection. But i want to get all programs installed on a PC. so i think i have to access both 64 bit and 32 bit hive. So how can i access 64 bit hive and 32 bit to all installed programs OR is there any other tricks to get same? Below is my existing code.

```
Option Explicit


Dim StrComputer As String
Dim sCompName As String

Dim sFileName As String

Function GetAddRemove(sComp)
  'Function credit to Torgeir Bakken
  Dim cnt, oReg, sBaseKey, iRC, aSubKeys
  Const HKLM = &H80000002 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
  Set oReg = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & _
              sComp & "/root/default:StdRegProv")
  sBaseKey = "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\"
  iRC = oReg.EnumKey(HKLM, sBaseKey, aSubKeys)

  Dim sKey, sValue, sTmp, sVersion, sDateValue, sYr, sMth, sDay

  For Each sKey In aSubKeys
    iRC = oReg.GetStringValue(HKLM, sBaseKey & sKey, "DisplayName", sValue)
    If iRC <> 0 Then
      oReg.GetStringValue HKLM, sBaseKey & sKey, "QuietDisplayName", sValue
    End If
    If sValue <> "" Then
      iRC = oReg.GetStringValue(HKLM, sBaseKey & sKey, _
                                "DisplayVersion", sVersion)
      If sVersion <> "" Then
        sValue = sValue & ",Ver: " & sVersion
      Else
        sValue = sValue
      End If
      sTmp = sTmp & sValue & vbCrLf
    cnt = cnt + 1
    End If
  Next
  sTmp = BubbleSort(sTmp)
  GetAddRemove = "INSTALLED SOFTWARE (" & cnt & ") - " & sCompName & _
                 " - " & Now() & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & sTmp
End Function

Function BubbleSort(sTmp)
  'cheapo bubble sort
  Dim aTmp, i, j, temp
  aTmp = Split(sTmp, vbCrLf)
  For i = UBound(aTmp) - 1 To 0 Step -1
    For j = 0 To i - 1
      If LCase(aTmp(j)) > LCase(aTmp(j + 1)) Then
        temp = aTmp(j + 1)
        aTmp(j + 1) = aTmp(j)
        aTmp(j) = temp
      End If
    Next
  Next
  BubbleSort = Join(aTmp, vbCrLf)
End Function

Function WriteFile(sData, sFileName)
 Dim intFile As Integer
  Dim strFile As String
  strFile = sFileName
  intFile = FreeFile
  Open strFile For Output As #intFile
    Print #intFile, sData
  Close #intFile
End Function

Private Sub Form_Load()
StrComputer = "."
sFileName = "D:\desktop\ins.txt"
Dim s As String
s = GetAddRemove(".")
Call WriteFile(s, sFileName)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

See `DONT_VIRTUALIZE`

```
C:\Users\User>reg flags /?

REG FLAGS KeyName [QUERY |
                   SET [DONT_VIRTUALIZE] [DONT_SILENT_FAIL] [RECURSE_FLAG]]

  Keyname    "HKLM\Software"[\SubKey] (Restricted to these keys on
        local machine only).
    SubKey   The full name of a registry key under HKLM\Software.
  DONT_VIRTUALIZE DONT_SILENT_FAIL RECURSE_FLAG
    Used with SET; flags specified on the command line will be set,
        while those not specified will be cleared.

Examples:

  REG FLAGS HKLM\Software\MyCo\MyApp QUERY
    Displays the current flags of the key MyApp.

  REG FLAGS HKLM\Software\MyCo\MyApp SET DONT_VIRTUALIZE /s
    Sets the DONT_VIRTUALIZE flag (and clears DONT_SILENT_FAIL and
    RECURSE_FLAG) on MyApp and all its subkeys
```

Start - All Programs - Accessories - Right click Command Prompt and choose Run As Administrator. Type (or copy and paste by right clicking in the Command Prompt window and choosing Paste). Type for table format

```
wmic /output:"%userprofile%\desktop\WindowsInstaller.html" product get /format:htable
```

or in a form format

```
wmic /output:"%userprofile%\desktop\WindowsInstaller.html" product get /format:hform
```

It will create a html file on the desktop.

Note

This is not a full list. This is only products installed with Windows Installer. There is no feature for everything.

However as I said in my previous post nearly everything is listed in the registry.

So to see it in a command prompt

```
reg query HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall /s
```

or in a file

```
reg query HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall /s>"%userprofile%\desktop\WindowsUninstall.txt"
```

To see it in notepad in a different format

Click Start - All Programs - Accessories - Right click Command Prompt and choose Run As Administrator. Type Regedit and navigate to

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
```

Right click the Uninstall key and choose Export. If you save as a reg file (there is also text file, they are slightly different text formats) you need to right click the file and choose Edit to view it.

To view **Windows Updates**

```
wmic /output:"%userprofile%\desktop\WindowsUpdate.html" qfe  get /format:htable
```

### .